# PHPExcel only populating 1st value from array in dropdown

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

I have a dropdown I would like to populate in excel from php. I've tested my script for calling the array `$sql_temp = "SELECT tempID FROM temp_sensor_specs WHERE statusTYPE ='SPARE'";`

```
INSERT INTO `temp_sensor_specs` (`tempId`) VALUES
('T001'),
('T005'),
('T006'),
('T011'),
('T012'),
('T015'),
('T017'),
('T023'),
('T028'),
('T029'),
('T030'),
```

Then I imploded the array to make it a string `$templistimp = implode (", ", $row_temp);` I also removed the brakets hoping that would help, it didn't. o my dropdown looks like this:

[image]

I would like to to look more like its html brother which looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
$sql_temp = "SELECT `tempID` FROM `temp_sensor_specs` WHERE `statusTYPE`='SPARE'";
$result_temp = mysqli_query($link, $sql_temp);
$row_temp = mysqli_fetch_array($result_temp,MYSQLI_NUM);
$templistimp = implode (", ", $row_temp);
$templist = str_replace(array( '(', ')' ), '', $templistimp);

//Data Validation list
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B4')->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
$objValidation->setErrorStyle(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION);
$objValidation->setAllowBlank(true);
$objValidation->setShowDropDown(true);
$objValidation->setErrorTitle('Input error');
$objValidation->setError('Value is not in list');
$objValidation->setFormula1('"'.$templist.'"');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list should be formatted like:

```
$objValidation->setFormula1('"T001,T002,T003"');
```

but I'd suggest that you're only reading the first entry from your database

```
$row_temp = mysqli_fetch_array($result_temp,MYSQLI_NUM);
```

to populate the datavalidation list, so there will only be single entry in the list.

Note that MS Excel has a limit to the size of a datavalidation list, which is fixed at 256 characters (including the comma separators). If your list is likely to be larger, then it is better to store the data in cells (possibly in a  hidden worksheet or column) and then reference that cell range:

```
$objValidation->setFormula1('$D$2:$D$6');
```

The limit when providing a list from a range of cells is 32,767 items

Comment: hi @Mark Baker I began trying to do as you advised. But as you suggested I am only reading from the 1st line. May I ask how you concluded this? and what parameters I should check to get all values. This code for the array works well on the webpage, but for some reason not so well into excel.

Comment: How do I conclude that you're only reading the first row from the database result? `mysqli_fetch_array()` will only fetch a single result from your query resultset; you need to loop through fetching each record in turn, building your array

Comment: Thanks Mark, Sorry I should have done more reading on mysqli_fetch statements 1st. I ended up using mysqli_fetch_all(). Everything is working fine and bonus that $objValidation->setFormula1('DropdownSheet!$A$3:$A$200'); will not return any null values. your patience is much appreciated.